# Issues when trying to migrate

Tags: laravel

I am having a problem when trying to make migrate.

> MY DATABASE DOES NOT RECEIVE NEW MIGRATION, NO NEW FILES NO UPDATES

From my project;

I do:

```
php artisan migrate
```

But nothing shows in my database, I already verify my database and my file `.env`

Both are correct.

Comment: I also did php artisan: install

Comment: createda new table:

Comment: php artisan make:migration create _newtable _table table create =new _table

Comment: I WILL APPRECIATE ANY HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you verified it, but please check again that the correct database information is entered in your `.env` file. It should be something like the following for a dev environment:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

You need to edit that data if you haven't and make sure it's correct. You also need to make sure that your database actually *exists*.

Also make sure you're actually entering the correct command. The general way you should making migrations is:

```
php artisan make:migration create_example_table --create=example
```

After that, run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Lastly, are you getting any errors in the console? If so, you need to edit your post and post them here.

Comment: I had already checked .env file and I replaced database name from my sql (I use phpadmin), and also I changed username and password as I entered on sql server, but there is no migration.

Comment: I had created a new table using artisan command (besides I have a users table that comes when downloading laravel project). After creating this new table I expected to upload  this new one to my database located in sql server, but  nothing happen

Comment: it shows your users yable already exists, mentions my users tables and not my new table that i just created. It is weird bcz it does not  EVEN  upload any changes made in default table users.....alwasy answer your table users already exits

Comment: Could you copy and paste your actual migration file in `database/migrations`?

Answer (score 0):

firts thanks for answering

I had already checked .env file and I replaced database name from my sql (I use phpadmin), and also I changed username and password as I entered on sql server, but there is no migration

I had created a new table using artisan command (besides I have a users table that comes when downloading laravel project). After creating this new table I expected to upload this new one to my database located in sql server, but nothing happen

it shows your users yable already exists, mentions my users tables and not my new table that i just created. It is weird bcz it does not EVEN upload any changes made in default table users.....always answer your table users already exits